# Display options on top of choice

Tags: select, positioning, show-hide, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 plugin for select element. I need to show select options over select choice so I set negative margin to select options. Options are showing over select choice but they did not stay opened. Maybe this is happen because of `onkeyup` event on select result item. But I have no clue how to resolve this problem.

This is example what I want:

HTML:

```
<select name="">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.select2-drop {
    margin-top: -26px;
}
```

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/quark2014/YC3kt/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first step i though is use the select2 event : select2-selecting

The code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
     minimumResultsForSearch: -1
  }).on('select2-selecting',function(e){

       e.preventDefault();

  });  


});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yoyog/1/edit)

But we still have problem Orz..

Comment: Thanks for help. But yes there is another problem :(